# error al filtrar productos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

estoy teniendo el siguiente problema que seria que al momento de mostrar los detalles de unos productos, no me estaria retornando nada, ni siquiera un error en consola como para poder guiarme. A continuacion dejo la imagen y el codigo.!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 const DetailProduct = () => {
 const { isbn13 } = useParams();
 const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
 useEffect(() => {
 const getProduct = async () => {
  fetch(`https://api.itbook.store/1.0/search/react.js/${isbn13}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      setBooks(res.books);
      setLoading(false);
    });
};
getProduct();
}, [isbn13]);

const Loading = () => {
return <>Loading...</>;
};

const ShowProduct = () => {
return (
  <>
    <div className="col-md-6">
      <p>{books.title}</p>
    </div>
  </>
);
};
return (
<div>
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">{loading ? <Loading /> : <ShowProduct />}</div>
  </div>
</div>
);
};
```

Comment: No muestra nada porque `books.title` no existe... books es un `array` y un array no tiene la propiedad title. Lo que debes hacer es recorrer el array de books y para cada uno crear un componente `ShowProduct` y le pasas el libro que quieres mostrar como prop `<ShowProduct book={book}>` y dentro de  `ShowProduct` usas `book.title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te dije en el comentario, debes crear un componente `ShowProduct` por cada libro y acceder a las propiedades de ese libro especifico.

Y no es necesario que definas el componente de `Loading` y el de `ShowProduct` dentro de `DetailProduct`

```js
const Loading = () => {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
};

const ShowProduct = ({ book }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {book && (
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <p>Titulo: {book.title}</p>
          <p>Subtitulo: {book.subtitle}</p>
          <p>Autores: {book.authors}</p>
          <p>etc...</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

function DetailProduct () {
  const isbn13 = "9781484206485"; //Lo pongo como constante para poder ejecutarlo aqui mismo dentro de stack overflow
  const [book, setBook] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = () => {
      fetch(`https://api.itbook.store/1.0/books/${isbn13}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          setBook(res);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    };
    getProduct();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
         {loading ? <Loading /> : <ShowProduct book={book} />}
      </div>
   </div>
   
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<DetailProduct  />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, yo ya habia logrado filtrar todos los productos, lo que necesitaba ahora era filtrarlos de a uno, cuando los mapeo me los devuelve los titulos de todos los libros y no puedo lograr hacer los detalles de cada uno de los libros por separado!

Comment: En el componente ShowProduct ya tienes la variable book, de la cual puedes mostrar las propiedades que desees. O si lo que quieres es mostrar un único libro basado en el ISBN debes llamar es al endpoint: `https://api.itbook.store/1.0/books/{isbn}` y no a search como lo haces actualmente

Comment: Ya acabo de actualizar mi respuesta accediendo a los datos de un unico libro

Comment: gracias genio!!